# Is there an hot reload alternative for Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I'm aware that when developing in Xamarin.Forms I have available some tools for hot reloading, such as:

- https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/HotReload
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Xamarin.XamarinLiveReload
- https://www.livexaml.com/

However I wasn't able to find an equivalent alternative for Xamarin.Android. Is there an alternative out there that I can use for hot reloading on Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways of creating a layout in Xamarin Android:

1. Using axml layouts - If you upgrade to the latest Xamarin & Visual Studio on a Mac, you will notice that the designer view for a layout gets updated in real time with the axml code. So technically it's live reloading.
2. Inside the fragment(CS file) - For this you can use Continuous, as you can see it in use [here](https://www.ryandavis.io/declarative-code-based-xamarin-forms-ui/). Ryan Davis is available on Twitter, and he's pretty quick to respond